# Change year in POSIXct in data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, posixct

I need to change some incorrect years in a POSIXct column in a data.table.

Here is a simple data.table.

```
y = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:30:00", "2107-08-14 15:13:00", "2017-08-14 11:12:13"))
x = as.data.table(y)
```

I can find the rows that do not have a date in the year 2017 with this

```
 x[year(y) != 2017,]
```

Now I would like to replace the incorrect year values (because upon inspection of the rows I can see that they are typos) with "2017".

I have tried this

```
x[year(y) != 2017, year(y) == 2017]
```

and this

```
x[year(y) != 2017, year(y) := 2017]
```

But neither worked.
I did manage to make the change using gsub

```
new = x[, gsub("2107", "2017", y)]
new = x[, gsub("2018", "2017", y)]
```

But the output is not a data table, and even if I use as.data.table and as.POSIXct to make sure the new dates are in the correct format and the output is a data table, the rows still do not appear to have taken on the year value of 2017.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to assign it back to `x` using `:=`, e.g. `x[, x := as.POSIXct(gsub("2107", "2017", x))]`. Though if you want to replace all the no-2017 years, I would vectorize as follows `library(stringi) ; x[year(x) != 2017, x := as.POSIXct(stri_replace_all_fixed(x, year(x), "2017"))]`. Also, I'm not sure why are you keep using `y`. You have a column called `x` within `x`, so just use it.

Comment: Thanks David!  I figured I was missing a step somewhere. Sorry about the confusion with x and y, I was trying to mimic what was going on in my real data table.